How are images for a React application managed in production?
Am following a React tutorial which has some images in the src/assets folder and imports them by giving a relative path to component files. I'm a bit confused how this is handled for production.
I understand that generally webpack bundles all the js and css together to create a single bundle file but if you have large image file assets in your src folder, then how are they handled for production? Do you need to upload them into the same /assets folder structure when you deploy your app to a web server as the code will still be looking for those relative path references to display the images?

In general, images aren't bundled with JavaScript.
Depending on your configuration, Webpack will "copy" it to the build folder for you, so you just have to deploy 1 folder.
You can still use some plugins to make Webpack optimize your images during the build process.
Try to build your app and check the results to see if the images are there.
If not, you either have to install a webpack plugin, or add a command to copy the images to the build folder.

This is a question around some tutorials I've done in the past. If the images were in the src folder then those  tags in production will make a request to some folder path right? so does the src/assets folder get created again in production?
